# BST to Linked list

Tags: linked-list, binary-search-tree

Can anyone suggest an algorithm to convert a Binary Search Tree to a singly linked list.
Also note that at each step of conversion the highest values node in the list should point to the smallest valued node in the list.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! :) If this is a homework problem, please add the [tag:homework] tag to your post with the [edit] link immediately underneath your question. We like to know when we've got homework problems so we can give better _hints_ towards finding the solution...

Comment: @Sarnold : better if you concentrate on providing an algorithm.

Comment: Its not a homework problem,its interview question of Microsoft

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(!tree.isEmpty())
{   
    Node node1 = tree.removeMin();
    Node node2;
    Node currentNode;
    Node temp;
    if(!tree.isEmpty())
    {
        node2 = tree.removeMax();
        node2.setNext(node1);
        currentNode = node2;
        while(!tree.isEmpty())
        {
            temp = tree.removeMin();
            temp.setNext(currentNode);
            currentNode = temp;
        }
    }
    Node head = temp;
}
```

This conforms to a singly linked list and the maximum value in the list always points to the least value in the list. No other qualifications were given.

Comment: - you seriously need to review your algorithm.

Comment: I accidentally made some changes while I was making it more legible. I believe that should work just fine now.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static LinkedListNode<Integer> constructLinkedList(BinaryTreeNode<Integer> root) {
if(root == null)
        return null;
    LinkedListNode<Integer> newHead = constructLinkedList(root.left);
    LinkedListNode<Integer> temp = newHead;
    if(newHead == null)
        newHead = new LinkedListNode<>(root.data);
    else
    {           
        while(temp != null && temp.next != null)
        {
            temp = temp.next;
        }
        temp.next = new LinkedListNode<>(root.data);
    }
    LinkedListNode<Integer> rightHead = constructLinkedList(root.right);
    if(newHead.next == null)
        newHead.next = rightHead;
    else
        temp.next.next = rightHead;
    return newHead;
}
```